# I don't understand JWT refresh token's behaviour (LARAVEL)

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

I have just tried JWT auth with LARAVEL and this https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth

But there's something i can't understand. In their config they put :

```
'ttl' => env('JWT_TTL', 60), // in munutes
'refresh_ttl' => env('JWT_REFRESH_TTL', 20160), // in minutes
```

What i understant : the token's live is 1hour and can be refreshed within 2 weeks

But after 3hours, if i try to query something, it says "token expired".

Does this system mean, a user must get his token updated / refreshed within every hour but with a limit of 2 weeks ? I don't get it.

How can a user persist login with this kind of system ? How is the refresh Token useful when after the first hour, though it hasn't been 2 weeks yet, i can't get a fresh token ?

thanks

UPDATE: CODE

config/jwt.php

```
'ttl' => 2, // 2 minutes
'refresh_ttl' => 5, // 5 minutes
```

routes/api.php

```
Route::post('/login', 'AuthController@login');
Route::get('/test', 'AuthController@test')->middleware('jwt.auth', 'jwt.refresh');
```

Http/Controllers/AuthController

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use JWTAuth;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function test()
    {
        return response()->json(['coucou' => 1]);
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        // grab credentials from the request
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        try {
            // attempt to verify the credentials and create a token for the user
            if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
                return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
            }
        } catch (JWTException $e) {
            // something went wrong whilst attempting to encode the token
            return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
        }

        // all good so return the token
        return response()->json(compact('token'));
    }
}
```

AND THIS IS THE FLOW :

**request** to **/login** with {username: xxx, password: xxx}
**response** of **/login** > {token: xxxxxxx}

**request** to **/test** straight after (10 secs) with **Bearer xxxxxx**
**response** of **/test** > the good json response with NEW TOKEN in HEADER

**request** to **/test** after 3 minutes (so 3mins 10 secs have past now, less than the 5min of refresh limit)
**response** of **/test** > token expired

I don't understand.

Answer (score 4):

After the access token is expired you can use the refresh token to get a new access token without asking the user to input his username and password again. 
Only after the refresh token is expired, the user needs to login again.

> But after 3hours, if i try to query something, it says "token expired".

that's because the access token is expired.

> Does this system mean, a user must get his token updated / refreshed within every hour but with a limit of 2 weeks ? I don't get it.

yes. You keep the refresh token in your client system and use it to request a new access token when the access token is expired.

Comment: well it doesn't work, even with the refresh token, used it says : token expired after an hour

Comment: maybe i'm doing it wrong, how can i acheive this : " you can use the refresh token to get a new access token without asking the user to input " ?

Comment: you have to send the refresh token to the same endpoint from which you got the access token before. The Request header should then contain

Comment: you have to send the refresh token to the same endpoint from which you got the access token before. The Request header should then contain grant_type=refresh_token refresh_token=<your refresh token>              the reply will be a new access token and only with the new access token you'll get access to the data again.

Comment: can you show me a simple snippet, because i can't get thi right. The thing is, if i try to get an endpoint and it fails then i have to try to refresh the token before a re try my end point, it gives a very weird flow in my opinion.

Si my UPDATED POST to know what i have

Comment: Also, you should remove the "jwt.refresh" middleware. That´s for one-pass tokens, it has nothing to do with implementing a token refresh procedure.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, finally I have something that works.

1. Remove "jwt.refresh" from your middleware. This is for one-pass-tokens as I´ve commented above.
2. I couldn´t get JWTAuth::refresh() to work with blacklists enabled. A "TokenBlacklistedException" is thrown when I call JWTAuth::refresh() even though I know its only expired since I do this in the catch block for "TokenExpiredException". Bug? Workaround:

   `JWT_BLACKLIST_ENABLED=false`
3. You need to have a refresh endpoint you can call if /test returns 401. I use same as login, but it´s kind of custom in my case.

```
...
    try
    {
      if($token = JWTAuth::getToken())
      {
        JWTAuth::checkOrFail();
      }
      $user = JWTAuth::authenticate();
    }
    catch(TokenExpiredException $e)
    {
      JWTAuth::setToken(JWTAuth::refresh());
      $user = JWTAuth::authenticate();
    }
    if($user /*&& check $user against parameter or not*/) 
    {
       return response()->json([
          'user' => $user->profile(),
          'accessToken'=> JWTAuth::getToken()->get(),
       ], 200);
    }
    else 
    {
        return response()->json(false, 401); //show login form
    } ...
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did for mine, I have to set the token time to be valid to 24 hours by doing this

```
'ttl' => env('JWT_TTL', 1400)
```

I changed the 60 to 1440, and my token now last for a day.

Comment: You can remove the jwt.refresh middleware from your route.