# How to generate JWT refresh token in Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, jwt, refresh-token

First off, let me admit that I'm new to APIs, and right now I'm working on JWT with Laravel. I'm using tymon\jwt-auth (`tymon/jwt-auth:dev-develop --prefer-source` to be specific). I went through some tutorials and was able to generate JWT access token.

Here is my login code:

```
public function login() {
    $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);
    if (!$token = auth('api')->attempt($credentials)) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
    }
    return response()->json([
        'status' => 'success',
        'message' => 'Login successful',
        'data' => [
          'access_token' => $token,
        ],
    ]);
}
```

I also need to get refresh token along with the access token, and cannot find code that works in my case.

I tried adding these lines in the code:

```
$refresh_token = JWTAuth::refresh($token);
```

but the postman returns with this error:

> A token is required in file
>   /var/www/brochill-api/vendor/tymon/jwt-auth/src/JWT.php on line 331

I can also provide other configuration snippets I used if needed. Please help!

Comment: You can check it at here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41325250/i-dont-understand-jwt-refresh-tokens-behaviour-laravel

Comment: assuming you set it up correctly, you just call `auth()->refresh()` without passing anything as it's a protected endpoint and will parse the existing token

Comment: @ahmad , in my case, `auth()->refresh()` didn't do the trick, after some trial and error, I added `auth('api')->refresh($token)` and that's generating the refresh token. So I can say the problem is solved. Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 3):

Let's start with creating a `/refresh` route:

```
Route::post('refresh', 'AuthController@refresh');
```

Now, in the `AuthController`,

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new AuthController instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login']]);
    }

    /**
     * Get a JWT via given credentials.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function login()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Get the authenticated User.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function me()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Log the user out (Invalidate the token).
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function logout()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Refresh a token.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function refresh()
    {
        return $this->respondWithToken(auth()->refresh());
    }

    /**
     * Get the token array structure.
     *
     * @param  string $token
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    protected function respondWithToken($token)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'access_token' => $token,
            'token_type' => 'bearer',
            'expires_in' => auth()->factory()->getTTL() * 60
        ]);
    }
}
```

The `refresh()` function refreshes the access token and invalidates the current one.

For more info on these, you can checkout the official documentation of `tymon/jwt-auth`, which can be found [here](https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/).

Comment: what if the token is expired and then try to refresh token? Please note: refresh_ttl=2 weeks, ttl=15 (min)